# Whats the query to get recent pokes on facebook?

Tags: javascript, sql, facebook, schema

Unfortunaly facebook gave us a good api, but without of and documentation about the tables schema. How can i build a valif query to get recent pokes?

Answer (score 1):

The old deprecated Facebook Rest API method called [notifications.get](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.get/) allows you to get the current number of Facebook pokes received and the user id of the latest person to poke you.

Sending pokes are not supported by the Facebook API. You would have to break the Facebook terms of service and resort to scraping the users home page.  I am guessing that is what the iPad app Friendly is doing, unless Facebook granted them access to an undocumented api (very unlikely).

Comment: Do you have a citation or reference?

Comment: I found the notification.get, but unfortunaly i have no idea how to implement. I cannot find any working example how to build the needed parameter key for doing the request. My current app is using the new api and i still ave an session, but i need to know how to build the access token.